# How can I install Selenium WebDriver in Pycharm when encountering an SSL error with pip?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pip, pycharm, selenium-firefoxdriver

Selenium WebDriver in python(Pycharm)

It gives an error when I try to load the library "pip install selenium"

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not ava
ilable.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection br
oken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium
/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection br
oken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium
/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection br
oken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium
/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection br
oken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium
/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection br
oken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium
/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/selenium/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/selenium/ (Caused by
 SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not ava
ilable.

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPS
ConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(
"Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Installed OpenSSL but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Windows Users need to set below paths:

- `..\Anaconda3`
- `..\Anaconda3\scripts`
- `..\Anaconda3\Library\bin`

**Per user:**

1. Open Environment variable
2. Click <kbd>User Variable</kbd>
3. Close command prompt if already open and reopen it

**System wide** (requires restart)**:**

1. Open Environment variable
2. Click <kbd>System Variable</kbd>
3. Restart Windows